# Accessing path format used for routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'd like to be able to access the path format that was used for routing. For example, given the following configuration:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/users/:id/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'users/form.html',
            controller: 'UsersController'
        })
        .when('/users/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'users/show.html',
            controller: 'UsersController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

I'd like my `UsersController` to be able to gain access to the path format string (e.g. `'/users/:id/edit'`) that was used for the routing. The only way I have been able to find to do this is by injecting `$route` as a dependency in the controller and then accessing the property `$route.current.$$route.originalPath`. This works, but it uses the 'private' `$$route` property. I'd like to use a more 'legal' approach if possible.

Comment: `$location.hash()` would give you the same..

Comment: @pankajparkar are you sure? It returns nothing for me, which is consistent with what I'd expect based on the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: oh..thats my bad..that would be `$location.url()` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url

Comment: Not quite -- that gives me the exact URL. I'm looking for the string with the parameter in it -- `/users/:id/edit`

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` pattern is to "protect" the libraries' internals from tinkering with them by unaware users. That being said there are sometimes cases when you need to do tinker with the internals ;), e.g. you're creating something specific and what is not a typical use case.

Having to know the path format used *is* pretty atypical, and as such I think that using `$route.current.$$route.originalPath` is probably the right solution. It is normally "hidden" because usually we don't need this value, but in the end they do have a function in the app and it seems you need that.